# Office 365 Deleted user

Tags: active-directory, office365, exchange-server

we are running hybrid environment. Office 365 (exchange 2016 online) and AD on premise. I deleted one user ID from AD and after AD synced with Exchange online users has been deleted from Exchange online but when I login to EMC I see the deleted user mailbox under  Home > Deleted Users but when I go to Admin center > Exchange > Recipients > Mailboxes > Deleted mailboxes I cant find the deleted user mailbox.
I need to merge this deleted user mailbox to another new ID\mailbox I have created but only two ways I know is by going to the deleted mailboxes under recipients or use Guid to merge account and when I ran this PS command below, user mailbox does show up in the soft deleted exported list.

`Get-Mailbox -SoftDeletedMailbox | select DisplayName, DistinguishedName, Guid, WindowsEmailAddress,PrimarySmtpAddress, Alias, UserPrincipalName  | export-csv c:\temp\softdeleted.csv -NoTypeInformation`

So what is the different between deleted mailbox under EMC and deleted mailboxes under Admin Center.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with programming?

Comment: I guess my command for Get-Mailbox -SoftDeletedMailbox above  doesnt show the deleted mailbox under EMC > deleted mailboxes. What PS command that will show the deleted mailboxes under EMC > deleted mailboxes. do I need to update my command somehow?